# "expression must be an l-value or function designator" error when taking the address of this

Tags: c++, this, lvalue, prvalue

I'm trying to do this in C++:

```
class Abc
{
   int callFunction1()
};

void function1(Abc** c1) {//do something}

int Abc::callFunction1()
{
   function1(&this);
   return 0;
}
```

And I get "expression must be an l-value or function designator" error in visual studio 2015. So I don't understand where I go wrong. To my knowledge, `&this` should have the type `Abc**` right?

The function definition isn't mine to change. So I can't just change the parameter type.

Comment: In what case do you need to use a pointer to a pointer? I'd argue that it's not the proper approach most of the time

Comment: `"&this" should have type Abc** right?` It would have such type, but `this` is not an lvalue, as the error says. You can't apply `&` to it.

Comment: `this` may have a pointer type, but it's not a variable.

Comment: Change the function signature to: `void function1(Abc* c1)` and in then: `function1(this);`

Comment: @UnholySheep this is defined by others, I'm working on a project based on their defination...

Comment: A simple `auto p = this; function1(&p);` will work.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, as I said I can't change the definition, so are there any chance for me to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, there is....

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry...Thank you! This is brilliant!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is clear enough. Since `this` is not an lvalue, you cannot take its address. If you just want the address of the object, then just pass `this`, not `&this`, and change the function declaration to:

```
void function1(Abc* c1) //To just pass a pointer
```

However, since you mentioned you cannot change the definition of the function, you can create a temporary variable and pass its address:

```
auto temp = this;
function1(&temp);
```

How this works:

1. Since [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) is a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) and cannot have its address taken, you need something to point to it to turn it into an lvalue, here `temp`.
2. Now that `temp` points to `this`, taking `temp`'s address will effectively take `this`'s address, albeit indirectly.
3. Therefore, since you are passing the address of an lvalue to `function1`, the code compiles and works as expected.

Comment: "The error is clear enough" I have to disagree because "lvalue" is not a word, and without knowing more about it, the error is opaque.  It's a little rude to imply beginners should just know what the problem is by reading that, I think...

Answer (score 5):

From the C++ Standard (9.2.2.1 The this pointer)

> 1 In the body of a non-static (9.2.1) member function, **the keyword
>   this is a prvalue expression** whose value is the address of the
>   object for which the function is called.

and (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 3 The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. **The
>   operand shall be an lvalue** or a qualified-id....

To make it more clear consider the following code snippet.

If for example you have a declaration

```
int x = 10;
```

then you may not write

```
int **p = &&x;
```

In the right expression `&x` is a `prvalue` and according to the second quote from the Standard you may not apply the unary operator `&` to the `prvalue`.

You could write

```
int *q = &x;
int **p = &q;
```

because `q` is `lvalue`.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `this` is an rvalue, the same way that the expressions `137` or `'a'` are, and so you can't take its address.

If you want to get a pointer to a pointer to `this`, you'll need to create a new variable of the right type:

```
auto* ptr = this;
doSomething(&ptr);
```